# Moving local Geoserver's data directory to production server unable to create new store

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a local GeoServer running on tomcat which using a PostGIS store to get layers from the PostgreSQL database. There is a production server that runs the same version of my local GeoServer and PostgreSQL database. In order to apply changes in layers and layer groups of my local GeoServer, I copied and replaced the data directory to production GeoServer. After restarting the tomcat on the production server, Geoserver unable to load Layers and Layer Preview pages on the web interface. Trying to change the host address of the store or creating a new one, it gives me this error:

```
Error creating data store with the provided parameters: Failed to upgrade lock from read to write state, please re-try the configuration operation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which OS you are using or how you made the copy, but the most likely error is a permissions or ownership one.

Make sure that the user which is running GeoServer has permission to read, write and execute on the data dir. On linux machines I've seen issues with `uid` and `gid` differences between machines depending on how the copy id carried out. On Windows I've seen issues just because windows and the virus scanner feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

When using the community function jdbcconfig, the same issues.

It seems that an error occurs because file locking of catalog is performed.

Since the data directory is not used by using JDBCconfig, the `file lock` has been improved by setting it to `Lock Disable`.

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#file-locking